# Create Localizable.stringsdict file from XCode Editor

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Does anybody know how to create a `.stringsdict` file in Xcode? When I dragged a separate .stringsdict file using `Finder` into ./en.lproj directory, it wasn't seen in the project navigator.

Answer (score 3):

Add a property list file to the project (choose File > New > File and select Property List from the sheet). In the project navigator, change the file name to Localizable.stringsdict

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW10